# Greyed-out Questions

Tags: support, bug

Sometimes questions appear in a greyed-out form. For instance, here's a screen grab from just now, the first two questions in the list are greyed-out:

[image]

I can't ascertain why this might occur. Sometimes the greyed-out questions have answers, sometimes they don't. Reloading the page has no effect. I don't see any other distinguishing characteristics.

What does this greyed-out status indicate?

EDIT...later the same day.

Seems to be a Safari problem. The greyed-out entries appear only in macOS (11.5.2) running Safari (14.1.2). Google Chrome (v.92.0.4515.159), Firefox (v.84.0.2), and Opera (v.77.0.4054.277) all display correctly.

Clearing Safari's history and caches has no effect, and the greyed-out status continues.

I've flagged this to be moved to [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Do you have any tags set to "ignore" ?  Are they on the greyed questions?

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the tag [eu-citizens]. The questions should be grayed out in other browsers as well, but it only works when you're logged in.

Comment: Both of you figured it out - this was not about Safari or macOS, but was about logging in with the tag [eu-citizens] set to "ignore." No idea how I set "ignore."  In any event, removing the "ignore" setting eliminated the greying-out of the two questions. If one or both of you post this as an answer, I'll cheerfully vote it up and accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It means you've ignored one of the tags on the question.

As noted by Chenmunka and Glorfindel in the comments, this is because you've ignored one or more of the tags on the greyed-out questions.

See this Q&A on MSE: [What do "watched tags" and "ignored tags" do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19173/335251)

> To ignore a tag, do one of the following:
>
> - In the tag’s tooltip, click on the "Ignore Tag" button.
> - On the main page’s sidebar, click on *edit* next to *Favorite Tags.*
> - On [`/users/preferences`](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/preferences), use the respective field in the *Tags* section.
>
> Note that [you can use wildcards](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/interesting-and-ignored-tags-now-support-wildcards/) in the latter two.
>
> This has the following effects:
>
> - By default, questions with these tags are shown faded; they are still visible but less prominent. It is possible to hide them
>   completely, for more details see: [How do I hide posts matching my
>   ignored tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19177/335251)
> - On Stack Overflow, this affects how questions are displayed on the home page *(Recent questions)* and the various questions pages.